# Running a solenoid pump with N-channel MOSFET

Tags: arduino, mosfet, solenoid

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs2kya.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to run a solenoid pump(L2 in the diagram) using a pulse generated by an Arduino. The pump is designed to run on rectified 24VAC, but the manufacturer says that running on a 24VDC 10ms pulsed square wave at varying frequencies works fine. Right now I have the pump set up in the configuration above. When I send my signal from the Arduino , I get no response. Upon testing the MOSFET with my multimeter, I found it to be no good. My question is, before I buy more MOSFET's, is this the best way to set up this circuit or are there better switches for this application? Is this the proper way to wire up my fly back diode? Is there a better way to protect my MOSFET? I apologize if I have not asked this question properly, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Is your dc/dc converter an isolated type? If so, there is no return path for the arduino to drive the mosfet. Connect 0V of arduino to 0V of the 24V circuit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that line. I do have the Arduino to the common ground as I now have shown in the schematic.

Comment: That should work, as long as you're not exceeding the rating of anything. It's better if you connect the diode nearer to the 24v supply on one side and and the mosfet drain on the other, that way it can dissipate flyback energy from the solenoid leads as well as the solenoid itself, but it should work ok as you have it as long as the leads are only like 6 in.

Comment: Ensure D2 polarity is as shown. If reversed it may destroy MOSFET. | Your circuit looks OK.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon -- indeed!  I was just sent a board by a customer, the schematic was correct but the flyback diode was reversed during assembly, and ... MOSFET let out the magic smoke.